# Problems with Updates, Service Worker

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am developing a PWA and I am shipping a lot of updates.

I have a service worker in the background as usual. But I cannot figure out a good update strategy.

By default the PWA update itself when all tabs are closed - for some users that might be never or months later, right? Does that mean breaking API Changes are impossible or how is that supposed to be?
Currently, I use the skipWaiting functionality which works fine, but in the InAppBrowser of Instagram, users get a blank screen each time the service worker forces the update.

What am I doing wrong? How are you guys solving the problems? Is SSR regarding this better?

Thanks :)

Alex